# Character Spacing in Editable PDFs

Tags: pdf

I am creating editable PDFs in Acrobat X (I also have Acrobat XI). However, I am designing wedding envelopes and wish to set character spacing to give a more elegant look. Line spacing etc are available - does anyone know a workaround for character spacing?

Comment: You couldn't do that, it is not possible in Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would work with single line fields.

Single line fields do have the Comb property, which is intented for filling forms where you have those many böxlis, one per character.

With an appropriate combination of field length and number of comb boxes, you can create an expansion of the string. You would have to set the border ccolor of the field to transparent, in order to make it invisible.

I am not quite sure whether you can change the character spacing with richText enabled; you'd have to try it, and also consider the span properties in JavaScript (not every property of a richText field is accessible via user interface, and not every property is accessible via JavaScript)